# How can I create a nested dictionary from existing lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to combine a set of lists into an organized dictionary.
The existing lists are in the following format:

```
index = [1, 2]
keys = [key1, key2, key3]
values_k1 = [a, b, c]
values_k2 = [d, e, f]
```

I want to organize those lists into the following dictionary:

```
d = {'1': {'key1':'a','key2':'b','key3':'c'}, '2': {'key1':'d','key2':'e','key3','f'}}
```

Comment: You can use nested dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: Having separate `values_k1`, `values_k2`, etc. variables makes this difficult, since you have to use variable variables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables for how to do that

Comment: Did you *try anything at all*?

Comment: @Barmar I'm going to go out on a limb and just guess the OP neglected to make them strings, otherwise, it isn't really (reasonably) possible

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant the variable names, not the list contents.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I assumed there could be a dynamic number of them, e.g. `values_k3`, `values_k4`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Look up [dictionary comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) api.

```
d = {
    i: dict(zip(keys, values)) 
    for i, values in zip(index, [values_k1, values_k2])
}
```

If the index is always incremental you can remove the index array and do something like this:

```
all_values = [values_k1, values_k2]
d = {
    i: dict(zip(keys, values)) 
    for i, values in enumerate(all_values)
}
```

And if `d` always has keys that are incremental you might as well use a list which can be accessed by index value anyways:

```
all_values = [values_k1, values_k2]
d = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in all_values]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you should, but you can make a nested dictionary comprehension.

```py
{i:{k:v for k,v in zip(keys,vals)} for i,vals in zip(index,(values_k1, values_k2))}
```